# npm publish error Assertion failed: (encoding == BINARY)

Tags: node.js, npm

I've published a package to npm once before, but for some reason I'm getting this cryptic error message when I try to publish:

```
Assertion failed: (encoding == BINARY), function DecodeWrite, file ../src/node.cc, line 1201.
Abort trap: 6
```

I've been following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/1318304) to publish my first one a little while ago. I've done an npm update from within my package dir, and made sure all the dependencies are listed in the package.json file. My npm version is 1.3.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went out of sync between updates. I found this guide: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4434

I updated everything on that list, and now publish works, and I'm on node -v 0.10.25 (up from 0.8.x) and npm -v 1.3.24